# Using := in data.table with paste()

Tags: r, data.table

I have started using `data.table` for a large population model. So far, I have been impressed because using the data.table structure decreases my simulation run times by about 30%. I am trying to further optimize my code and have included a simplified example. My two questions are:

1. Is is possible to use the `:=` operator with this code?
2. Would using the `:=` operator be quicker (although, if I am able to answer my first question, I should be able to answer my question 2!)?

I am using R version 3.1.2 on a machine running Windows 7 with `data.table` version 1.9.4.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)

## Create  example table and set initial conditions
nYears = 10
exampleTable = data.table(Site = paste("Site", 1:3))
exampleTable[ , growthRate := c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3), ]
exampleTable[ , c(paste("popYears", 0:nYears, sep = "")) := 0, ]

exampleTable[ , "popYears0" := c(10, 12, 13)] # set the initial population size

for(yearIndex in 0:(nYears - 1)){
    exampleTable[[paste("popYears", yearIndex + 1, sep = "")]] <- 
    exampleTable[[paste("popYears", yearIndex, sep = "")]] * 
    exampleTable[, growthRate]
}
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
for(yearIndex in 0:(nYears - 1)){
    exampleTable[ , paste("popYears", yearIndex + 1, sep = "") := 
    paste("popYears", yearIndex, sep = "") * growthRate, ] 
}
```

However, this does not work because the paste does not work with the `data.table`, for example:

```
exampleTable[ , paste("popYears", yearIndex + 1, sep = "")]
# [1] "popYears10"
```

I have looked through the [data.table documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/). Section 2.9 of the FAQ uses `cat`, but this produces a null output.

```
exampleTable[ , cat(paste("popYears", yearIndex + 1, sep = ""))]
# [1] popYears10NULL
```

Also, I tried searching Google and rseek.org, but didn't find anything. If am missing an obvious search term, I would appreciate a search tip. I have always found searching for R operators to be hard because search engines don't like symbols (e.g., "`:=`") and "R" can be vague.

Comment: Not bad for someone that just started.  Nice question too.

Comment: You might like the `paste0()` function, which is a shortcut for `paste(..., sep = "")`. Saves a bit of typing.

Comment: Take a look at `set()`. Example: `for (i in 1:5) set(DT, i, 3L, i+1)` is considerably faster than `for (i in 1:5) DT[i, z:= i+1]` where `3L` is the position of `z`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
## Start with 1st three columns of example data
dt <- exampleTable[,1:3]

## Run for 1st five years
nYears <- 5
for(ii in seq_len(nYears)-1) {
    y0 <- as.symbol(paste0("popYears", ii))
    y1 <- paste0("popYears", ii+1)
    dt[, (y1) := eval(y0)*growthRate]
}

## Check that it worked
dt
#     Site growthRate popYears0 popYears1 popYears2 popYears3 popYears4 popYears5
#1: Site 1        1.1        10      11.0     12.10    13.310   14.6410  16.10510
#2: Site 2        1.2        12      14.4     17.28    20.736   24.8832  29.85984
#3: Site 3        1.3        13      16.9     21.97    28.561   37.1293  48.26809
```

**Edit:**

Because the possibility of speeding this up using `set()` keeps coming up in the comments, I'll throw this additional option out there.

```
nYears <- 5

## Things that only need to be calculated once can be taken out of the loop
r <- dt[["growthRate"]]
yy <- paste0("popYears", seq_len(nYears+1)-1)

## A loop using set() and data.table's nice compact syntax
for(ii in seq_len(nYears)) {
    set(dt, , yy[ii+1], r*dt[[yy[ii]]])
}

## Check results
dt
#     Site growthRate popYears0 popYears1 popYears2 popYears3 popYears4 popYears5
#1: Site 1        1.1        10      11.0     12.10    13.310   14.6410  16.10510
#2: Site 2        1.2        12      14.4     17.28    20.736   24.8832  29.85984
#3: Site 3        1.3        13      16.9     21.97    28.561   37.1293  48.26809
```

Comment: thank you for tip. This method is about 20% faster. For the reference of future readers, make sure your preallocate the `dt` data table in Josh's example (i.e., create the entire data.table before the loop or `dt <- exampleTable` in this example).

Comment: @RichardErickson, why preallocate? There were some unnecessary copies in `:=` that were [fixed recently](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/921) in the development version (1.9.5). Maybe worth giving a try. Or use `set()` from CRAN version.

Comment: @Arun, pre-allocating avoids creating new columns within the loop. I learned the trick when I first starting programming with [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html) and it also works with R. For my experiment, I set `nYears <- 10000`. On my machine and it took 16.30s to run my original test case; 29.72s to run Josh's example, and 13.28s to Josh's example with preallocating the `dt`. Also, I am currently checking out `set()` and have `?set` open now :)

Comment: As another way to optimize the code (but at the cost of readability), putting everything on one line in the `for` loop speeds up the calculation slightly to now take 11.95s on my machine: `for(ii in seq_len(nYears)-1) {
    dt[,(paste0("popYears", ii+1)):=eval(as.symbol(paste0("popYears", ii))
)*growthRate]`

Comment: @RichardErickson -- If you are *really* just wanting each column to be a fixed multiple of the previous one, the I imagine that something like this might be faster:  `nYears <- 5; nn <- seq_len(nYears); XX <- data.table(dt[,popYears0] * t (sapply(dt[,growthRate], function(X) X^(nn)))); setnames(XX, paste0("popYears", nn)); dt <- data.table(dt, XX)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks for your extra help. I am doing more than simply multiplying the column by the previous column, but was trying to reduce my problem and create a reproducible example. If had a simple linear problem, I wouldn't need a `for` loop :)

Comment: @RichardErickson That's what I figured. Thanks for the nicely minimal reproducible example. (And please do let us know if you find some faster solution using `set()` or something else!)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien. You're welcome. Thank you again for your help. I looked at `set()` but decided not to use it because I could not figure out how to use `paste` inside it. The workaround that uses column numbers is undesirable because column numbers are fragile (I learned this the hard way...). Also, I am using `data.table` because I am doing lots of calculations with large, but not huge, data. As an added bonus of `data.table`, I also like its syntax once I got the hand of it.

Comment: @RichardErickson, you're performing a full column plonk. I really doubt the column allocation is helping (as data.table over allocates column pointers, and adds column by reference). The two places I can think of improving speed are 1) use of `set()` that'd avoid the `[.data.table` generic method overhead (since you seem to run 10000 times or so) and 2) use `cmpFun()` on the function that takes a for-loop and `set()` to byte code compile it.. If you could you provide an example of your real scenario / data dimensions, I'd love to take a look at it.

Comment: @Arun The *apparent* downside (or at least relative incovenience) of `set()` is that expressions in its `j` argument don't have "direct" access to columns in `dt`. Is accessing the columns via `dt[["var"]]` then the most efficient way to get at them, as in the example code I just added?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, right on. The reason for suggesting `set()` is mostly because the loop is run 10K times.. and each time it'll have to dispatch to `[.data.table`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien (and, Arun). I thank both of you for your help. I choose 10000 just to push the simulation. In actuality, I run each simulation for ~30 times (30 model years). However, I am planning on replicating each simulation 100s or 1000s of times after I change initial conditions through a stochastic process. Right now, I am trying to optimize each simulation and figure out biologically what I want to save from each simulation.

Comment: @RichardErickson Yeah. As a sometime modeler myself, it sounds like you prob. shouldn't spend too much more time on this aspect of the optimization at least until you've got the rest of your workflow nailed down. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Struggling with column names is a strong indicator that the wide format is probably not the best choice for the given problem. Therefore, I suggest to do the computations in long form and to reshape the result from long to wide format, finally.

```
nYears = 10
params = data.table(Site = paste("Site", 1:3),
                    growthRate = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3), 
                    pop = c(10, 12, 13))
long <- params[CJ(Site = Site, Year = 0:nYears), on = "Site"][
  , growth := cumprod(shift(growthRate, fill = 1)), by = Site][
    , pop := pop * growth][]
dcast(long, Site + growthRate ~ sprintf("popYears%02i", Year), value.var = "pop")
```

> ```
>      Site growthRate popYears 0 popYears 1 popYears 2 popYears 3 popYears 4 popYears 5 popYears 6 popYears 7 popYears 8 popYears 9 popYears10
> 1: Site 1        1.1         10       11.0      12.10     13.310    14.6410   16.10510   17.71561   19.48717   21.43589   23.57948   25.93742
> 2: Site 2        1.2         12       14.4      17.28     20.736    24.8832   29.85984   35.83181   42.99817   51.59780   61.91736   74.30084
> 3: Site 3        1.3         13       16.9      21.97     28.561    37.1293   48.26809   62.74852   81.57307  106.04499  137.85849  179.21604
> ```

#### Explanation

First, the parameters are  expanded to cover 11 years (including year 0) using the cross join function `CJ()` and a subsequent right join on `Site`:

```
params[CJ(Site = Site, Year = 0:nYears), on = "Site"]
```

> ```
>        Site growthRate pop Year
>  1: Site 1        1.1  10    0
>  2: Site 1        1.1  10    1
>  3: Site 1        1.1  10    2
>  4: Site 1        1.1  10    3
>  5: Site 1        1.1  10    4
>  6: Site 1        1.1  10    5
>  7: Site 1        1.1  10    6
>  8: Site 1        1.1  10    7
>  9: Site 1        1.1  10    8
> 10: Site 1        1.1  10    9
> 11: Site 1        1.1  10   10
> 12: Site 2        1.2  12    0
> 13: Site 2        1.2  12    1
> 14: Site 2        1.2  12    2
> 15: Site 2        1.2  12    3
> 16: Site 2        1.2  12    4
> 17: Site 2        1.2  12    5
> 18: Site 2        1.2  12    6
> 19: Site 2        1.2  12    7
> 20: Site 2        1.2  12    8
> 21: Site 2        1.2  12    9
> 22: Site 2        1.2  12   10
> 23: Site 3        1.3  13    0
> 24: Site 3        1.3  13    1
> 25: Site 3        1.3  13    2
> 26: Site 3        1.3  13    3
> 27: Site 3        1.3  13    4
> 28: Site 3        1.3  13    5
> 29: Site 3        1.3  13    6
> 30: Site 3        1.3  13    7
> 31: Site 3        1.3  13    8
> 32: Site 3        1.3  13    9
> 33: Site 3        1.3  13   10
>       Site growthRate pop Year
> ```

Then the growth is computed from the shifted growth rates using the cumulative product function `cumprod()` separately for each `Site`. The shift is required to skip the initial year for each `Site`. Then the population is computed by multiplying with the intial population.

Finally, the data.table is reshaped from long to wide format using `dcast()`. The column headers are created *on-the-fly* using `sprintf()` to ensure the correct order of columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think your answer helps with my problem. In my minimalistic example, I made `growthRate` a linear operator. However, in the complete problem, `growthRate` is a non-linear operator that needs to be updated each time step. Hence, the `for` loop is required. Also, this was noted in the comments under the accepted answer.