# How to assign variable names with paste in data.frame or data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

As pointed out in the comments this question applies to `data.frame` as well as `data.table`.

`paste` does not work in `data.table()` directly:

```
> data.table(paste(hello)=c(1,2),paste(world)=c(3,4))
Error: unexpected '=' in "data.table(paste(hello)="
```

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785393/using-in-data-table-with-paste/) deals with assigning a variable name that is `pasted` by pre-assigning it to a variable and the using that variable when creating a new variable in an existing `data.table`:

```
y1 <- paste0("popYears", ii+1)
dt[, (y1) := eval(y0)*growthRate]
```

However that does not work when creating a new `data.table`:

```
> name1 <- paste("hello")
> name2 <- paste("world")
> data.table((name1)=c(1,2), (name2)=c(3,4))
Error: unexpected '=' in "data.table((name1)="
```

Is this intentional? Is there any way to fix this?

The main question is: how do I use paste to assign variable names when creating a `data.table`?

There *is* a solution to this, which is assigning the names after creating the `data.table`, but this requires a number of additional lines of code:

```
> name1 <- paste("hello")
> name2 <- paste("world")
> DT <- data.table(name1=c(1,2), name2=c(3,4))
> setnames(DT, "name1", name1)
> setnames(DT, "name2", name2)
> DT

   hello world
1:     1     3
2:     2     4
```

Comment: I don't think `data.table` can evaluate an expression on its LHS. This isn't specific to `data.table`, rather this is just how `data.frame` works. `data.frame((name1)=c(1,2), (name2)=c(3,4))` will give you the exact same error.

Comment: Hmm okay, I haven't used data.frames since I know of data.table so I haven't tried that, I'll edit my question regarding that.

Comment: don't assign any names to begin with, and then do `setnames(DT, c(name1, name2))`