# R Using paste in data.table to subset variable number of columns and calculate rowMeans

Tags: r, data.table, paste

I have started using `data.table` over the past week and am facing an issue. I have already looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785393/using-in-data-table-with-paste/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067235/how-to-assign-variable-names-with-paste-in-data-frame-or-data-table) but I am not entirely sure how it helps in my situation.

Here, is my sample data.

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(link = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), id = c(8395, 8738, 9788, 9789, 9908, 9920), person = c(2937837, 3092435, 3511555, 3511555, 3568112, 3575082), seqid = c(11, 14, 9, 1, 7, 10), time = c(NA, NA, 25372, 50700, NA, NA), max = c(14, 31, 9, 7, 8, 11), hr = c(NA, NA, 7, 14, NA, NA), minhr = c(11, 19, 7, 14, 7, 16), maxhr = c(11, 19, 7, 14, 7, 16), TRAVELTIME0.1avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59 ), TRAVELTIME1.2avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME2.3avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME3.4avg = c(59.2079086331819, 59.2079086331819, 59.2079086331819, 59.2079086331819, 59.2079086331819, 59.2079086331819 ), TRAVELTIME4.5avg = c(59.9182362587214, 59.9182362587214, 59.9182362587214, 59.9182362587214, 59.9182362587214, 59.9182362587214), TRAVELTIME5.6avg = c(60.4905040124798, 60.4905040124798, 60.4905040124798, 60.4905040124798, 60.4905040124798, 60.4905040124798), TRAVELTIME6.7avg = c(59.2897529410742, 59.2897529410742, 59.2897529410742, 59.2897529410742, 59.2897529410742, 59.2897529410742 ), TRAVELTIME7.8avg = c(59.2717176535874, 59.2717176535874, 59.2717176535874, 59.2717176535874, 59.2717176535874, 59.2717176535874), TRAVELTIME8.9avg = c(59.2569737174023, 59.2569737174023, 59.2569737174023, 59.2569737174023, 59.2569737174023, 59.2569737174023), TRAVELTIME9.10avg = c(59.2814811928216, 59.2814811928216, 59.2814811928216, 59.2814811928216, 59.2814811928216, 59.2814811928216 ), TRAVELTIME10.11avg = c(59.2084537775537, 59.2084537775537, 59.2084537775537, 59.2084537775537, 59.2084537775537, 59.2084537775537 ), TRAVELTIME11.12avg = c(59.0915653550983, 59.0915653550983, 59.0915653550983, 59.0915653550983, 59.0915653550983, 59.0915653550983 ), TRAVELTIME12.13avg = c(59.6765035434587, 59.6765035434587, 59.6765035434587, 59.6765035434587, 59.6765035434587, 59.6765035434587 ), TRAVELTIME13.14avg = c(59.246760177185, 59.246760177185, 59.246760177185, 59.246760177185, 59.246760177185, 59.246760177185), TRAVELTIME14.15avg = c(59.4095339982924, 59.4095339982924, 59.4095339982924, 59.4095339982924, 59.4095339982924, 59.4095339982924), TRAVELTIME15.16avg = c(59.5347570536373, 59.5347570536373, 59.5347570536373, 59.5347570536373, 59.5347570536373, 59.5347570536373 ), TRAVELTIME16.17avg = c(59.3799872977671, 59.3799872977671, 59.3799872977671, 59.3799872977671, 59.3799872977671, 59.3799872977671 ), TRAVELTIME17.18avg = c(59.1915498629857, 59.1915498629857, 59.1915498629857, 59.1915498629857, 59.1915498629857, 59.1915498629857 ), TRAVELTIME18.19avg = c(59.1663574471712, 59.1663574471712, 59.1663574471712, 59.1663574471712, 59.1663574471712, 59.1663574471712 ), TRAVELTIME19.20avg = c(59.0217772215269, 59.0217772215269, 59.0217772215269, 59.0217772215269, 59.0217772215269, 59.0217772215269 ), TRAVELTIME20.21avg = c(59.0893371757925, 59.0893371757925, 59.0893371757925, 59.0893371757925, 59.0893371757925, 59.0893371757925 ), TRAVELTIME21.22avg = c(59.0272727272727, 59.0272727272727, 59.0272727272727, 59.0272727272727, 59.0272727272727, 59.0272727272727 ), TRAVELTIME22.23avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME23.24avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME24.25avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME25.26avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59), TRAVELTIME26.27avg = c(59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59)), .Names = c("link", "id", "person", "seqid", "time", "max", "hr", "minhr", "maxhr", "TRAVELTIME0.1avg", "TRAVELTIME1.2avg", "TRAVELTIME2.3avg", "TRAVELTIME3.4avg", "TRAVELTIME4.5avg", "TRAVELTIME5.6avg", "TRAVELTIME6.7avg", "TRAVELTIME7.8avg", "TRAVELTIME8.9avg", "TRAVELTIME9.10avg", "TRAVELTIME10.11avg", "TRAVELTIME11.12avg", "TRAVELTIME12.13avg", "TRAVELTIME13.14avg", "TRAVELTIME14.15avg", "TRAVELTIME15.16avg", "TRAVELTIME16.17avg", "TRAVELTIME17.18avg", "TRAVELTIME18.19avg", "TRAVELTIME19.20avg", "TRAVELTIME20.21avg", "TRAVELTIME21.22avg", "TRAVELTIME22.23avg", "TRAVELTIME23.24avg", "TRAVELTIME24.25avg", "TRAVELTIME25.26avg", "TRAVELTIME26.27avg"), sorted = "link", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Update1: To avoid the issue of `internal.selfref` do `dt <- data.table(dt)` after you create `dt` using the above sample.

I want to use the *minhr* and *maxhr* variables to subset the travel times and calculate the `rowMeans` for those subsetted travel times and add it to the current *dt*. If *minhr* (or *maxhr*) is 11, the corresponding travel time column is *TRAVELTIME11.12avg*; if it is 19, the corresponding travel time column is *TRAVELTIME19.20avg*. So, if *minhr* is 9 and *maxhr* is 10 for a row, then I need to get the mean of *TRAVELTIME9.10avg* and *TRAVELTIME10.11avg*; similarly, if *minhr* is 15 and *maxhr* is 17 then I need to get the mean of *TRAVELTIME15.16avg*, *TRAVELTIME16.17avg*, and *TRAVELTIME17.18avg*.

I tried to approach the problem step-wise and used the following code for a simple case of uniform travel time columns across all the rows. It works fine.

```
> dt[,avg:=rowMeans(.SD[,TRAVELTIME10.11avg:TRAVELTIME12.13avg, with=FALSE]),by=.(id, seqid)]
```

Next, I tried to modify the above code by introducing `paste0()` to refer to the column names dynamically. But, this results in an error. Additionally, I have tried to use `as.symbol(paste0())`, `noquote(paste0())` and a couple of other unquoting techniques without any success.

```
   > dt[,avg:=rowMeans(.SD[,paste0("TRAVELTIME", minhr, "." , minhr+1, "avg"):paste0("TRAVELTIME", maxhr, "." , maxhr+1, "avg"), with=FALSE]),by=.(id, seqid)]

Error in paste0("TRAVELTIME", minhr, ".", minhr + 1, "avg"):paste0("TRAVELTIME",  : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Given this, I have two questions:

1) Why doesn't `data.table` recognize the column names if the paste command is used (even after unquoting the pasted strings) to subset columns as opposed to directly using the column names? Does it have anything to do with the unequal number of columns for every row?

2) Since I am unsuccessful, can you please suggest a way to find the mean over variable number of columns for every row, and add it back to the dt. I would appreciate if the suggestion leads to an efficient way, because, I already tried this using a simpler looping method and it takes a long time (approximately 12 to 15 hours for my entire dataset) for the size of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves the problem you were having with `paste0`:

```
tmp  <- paste0("TRAVELTIME", dt$minhr, "." , dt$minhr+1, "avg")
tmp1 <- paste0("TRAVELTIME", dt$maxhr, "." , dt$maxhr+1, "avg")
dt1  <- dt[,avg:=rowMeans(.SD[,get(tmp):get(tmp1), with=FALSE]),by=.(dt$id, dt$seqid)]
```

Someone will probably point out that you don't strictly need the `$` in the last line, but due to the nature of the problem you were having I felt this was useful for identifying and solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not know why the internal.selfref pointer is being reported. I removed it now. In any case, I employed the solution you suggested and the mean travel times appear to be the same across all the rows. Can you please confirm if you got different travel times across the rows using this solution?

Comment: @Gandalf I can't replicate your data because of the issue with `internal.selfref` (if I take it out I get a different error relating to it when I go to do aggregation; it's weird). I only know that this solves the problem with the `paste0` issue. If the aggregation logic isn't correct then that would still need to be fixed. I imagine that you could fix it with some conditional statements (either putting the conditions inside of `if` statements or by applying the 2 different aggregate functions to the relevant subsets of the data).

Comment: I think using `dt <- data.table(dt)` before your code solves the `internal.selfref`  issue. But, more importantly, I do not think the above code solves my issue. The logic seems to be intact, but I am guessing something is off in the procedural details because when I try `dt[,get(tmp):get(tmp1), with=FALSE]`, I getting a single vector titled *TRAVELTIME11.12avg*. My guess is this issue is a result of the unequal columns. But, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: I think, in the above code, only the first element in the vector is being used. Here is the error message. Please note that I had to discard the `get()` to generate this error and warning.
`dt[,(tmp):(tmp1), with=FALSE]`
`Error in (tmp):(tmp1) : NA/NaN argument`
`In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (tmp):(tmp1) :
  numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
2: In (tmp):(tmp1) :
  numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: I think, I found a solution based on your inputs. First I need to create a column named *rown* indicating the row number like so `dt[,rown:= as.numeric(row.names(dt))]`.  Then I create a function and call it as shown below:   

`func.dt <- function(rown, x, y) {
  
  tmp  <- paste0("TRAVELTIME", x, "." , x+1, "avg")
  tmp1 <- paste0("TRAVELTIME", y, "." , y+1, "avg")
  rowMeans(dt[rown,get(tmp):get(tmp1), with=FALSE])
  
}

dt[, func.dt(rown, minhr, maxhr), by=rown]`

This works absolutely fine. But, it is extremely slow. Can you suggest me any ways to make it fast?