# Using := with eval(as.symbol()) to create columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the `data.table` in `R` (version 3.3.2 on OS X 10.11.6) and have noticed a change in behavior from version 1.9.6 to 1.10.0 with respect to the use of the `:=` operator and a character string for name.

I am renaming columns inside of a loop based upon the index number. Previously, I had been using `eval(as.symbol("string"))` on both sides of `:=`, but this no longer works (this was based upon answers from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785393/using-in-data-table-with-paste)). Through trial and error, I figured out I needed use `("string")` on of the left side and `eval(as.symbol("string"))` on the right hand side.

Here is MCVE that demonstrates this behavior

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(col1 = 1:10, col2 = 11:20)

## the next lines would be inside a loop that is excluded to simplify this MCVE
colA = paste0("col", 1)
colB = paste0("col", 2)
colC = paste0("col", 3)

## Old code that worked with 1.9.6, but not longer works
dt[ , eval(as.symbol(colC)) := eval(as.symbol(colA)) + eval(as.symbol(colB))]

## New code that now works 1.10.0
dt[ , (colC) := eval(as.symbol(colA)) + eval(as.symbol(colB))]
```

I have looked through the `data.table` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and have not been able to figure out why this work around works. So, here is my question:

Why do I need the `eval(as.symbol("string"))` on the right side, but not on the left?

Comment: The FAQ is considered part of the docs and necessary reading. General advice there (question 1.6 https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in ) seems to be to build a single expression and eval that: `e = substitute(colC := ColA + ColB, list(ColA = as.symbol("col1"), ColB = as.symbol("col2"), colC = as.symbol("col3"))); dt[, eval(e)]`. I'm not sure why your code worked before but doesn't now, though.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. I've looked through the FAQ before, but hadn't noticed that section before. Also, that pointer helps me to know what to search for in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [discussion](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1188#issuecomment-127824969), it is now assumed that if `j` is a single string, it is evaluated as a symbol, so that, for example, `dt[, "col" := 3]` will also work.

There's be a fair bit of changing around with exactly when this became the default, but the full story is contained in both the previous post and the `data.table` [news](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md).

It may be of interest to you, however, that with

```
new_cols = c("j1", "j2")
dt[, (new_cols) := value]  # brackets so we don't just make a new_col col
```

or

```
dt[, c("j1", "j2") := value]
```

it may be possible for you to achieve the above without needing a loop

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(a = c(2, 3), b = c(5, 7), c = c(11, 13))

cols1 = sapply(c("a", "b"), as.symbol)
cols2 = sapply(c("b", "c"), as.symbol)
new_cols = c("d", "e")

> print(dt)
   a b  c
1: 2 5 11
2: 3 7 13

dt[, (new_cols) := purrr::map2(cols1, cols2, ~ eval(.x) + eval(.y))]

   a b  c  d  e
1: 2 5 11  7 16
2: 3 7 13 10 20
```

Comment: Fyi, you can simplify further, `"col1" :=` to `col1 :=` and `(c("j1", "j2")) :=` to `c("j1", "j2") :=` and all of the examples you give were possible since very early versions of the package. Your examples do not cover the "if `j` is a single string" case... Fwiw, that case was changed in 1.9.8, described in item 3 of the changelog: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md but does not seem relevant here.

Comment: I knew the latter had been previously available, but I wanted to note anyway that with the new syntax OP has adopted, more than one column can be added in case it benefits them. WRT the first example, I didn't know that was previously possible.  Have I incorrectly attributed the error?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure exactly why the OP's code stopped working, but I don't think it's related to the new "if `j` is a single string" behavior. I could be wrong, though. Btw, I think it's fine/good to keep in the `c("j1", "j2") :=` that you removed. I do it that way all the time.